# Showing that perfect secrecy implies adversarial indistinguishability

Tags: perfect-secrecy

I've been reading the proof in [these slides, the last page](http://www.cs.stevens.edu/%7Enicolosi/classes/16sp-cs579/scribing-10sp/l3.pdf), and the author is using the lemma:

$Pr[A(c)=1|M=m_0]=Pr[A(c)=1|M=m_1]$

I understand on the intuitive level that it's a consequence of the assumed perfect secrecy, but can someone provide a proof to the aforementioned?

Comment: The ciphertext $c$ is independent of the message rv $M$, so the conditionals are the same for either message.